# Adding new word to prestashop language

Tags: prestashop

I want to add new word to prestashop language.
For example I need to use word which is not defined yet in english language.
I want to add new word alias 'mouse' translation 'mouse'.
How to add it?

Comment: It depends where you want to display it? In back-office? Or front-office? You're creating a module or you modify template/core class?

Answer (score 1):

In your theme's template (.tpl) where you want this term, go to the element where you need it and add `{l s='Mouse'}`.

You'll then be able to translate the "Mouse" word using the theme translations in backoffice.

Note: you can add this word to a specific module like this `{l s='Mouse' mod='specific_module'}` then translate it using the Module translations.

Comment: using the theme translations in backoffice
https://ibb.co/F4vwyzs you mean here? which option?

Comment: Yes, that one, if you added the "word" using the simple notation {l s='Word'}, without the mod=''specific_module"